# Add space after LaTeX command

Tags: macros, spacing, expansion, shell-escape

I'd like to call a command from LaTeX, which looks like this:

```
bash -c "\myCommand -Tpdf #2.dot > #2.pdf"
```

`\myCommand` is replaced by string variable, however the space after is also removed
so I get `something-Tpdf` which is of course not understood by bash. How can I force LaTeX to leave a space in this string?

`\myCommand{}` doesn't help

Comment: We could do with a full MWE to see how you are setting this up: for example, usually `\myCommand{}` would work fine.

Comment: `\myCommand\space` should work; but you should add some context to your question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to add a space in an expandable way, which is required for `\write18` system calls you can do so using the `\space` macro which is defined like `\newcommand*{\space}{ }` (actually `\def\space{ }`) and therefore expands to a single space.

So you can write your command string like:

```
bash -c "\myCommand\space -Tpdf #2.dot > #2.pdf"
```

The explicit space is required because spaces after a macro are removed, because they are taken as separator between the macro name and the text afterwards.
The usual way to add `{}` after it would preserve the space behind it, but this is only good for *typesetting* the text where the braces are ignored. If you want the text in an expandable context, like to write it into an external (auxiliary) file, to the shell (like in this case) or build a macro name from it (advanced topic), then the `{}` are unwanted and usually cause trouble.